# Inserting row from database to another

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am trying  to insert a row from a database server to another database server in a different environment using pymysql

```
prod_conn = pymysql.connect(
        prod_common_db_endpoint,
        prod_user,
        prod_password,
        prod_common_table_name)

prod_cursor = prod_conn.cursor()


prod_ConnectFirm_table = prod_cursor.execute("select * from Common.ConnectFirm where FirmId = " + prod_source_firm + ";")
for row in prod_ConnectFirm_table:
    ConnectFirmId = int(row[1])
    ConnectFirmName = (row[2])
    FirmId = int(row[3])
    isDeleted = (row[4])
    tags = (row[5])
    createdDate = (row[6])
    createdBy = int(row[7])
    editedDate = (row[8])
    editedBy = int(row[9])


conn = pymysql.connect(target_common_db_endpoint, user, password, common_schema_name)

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Common.ConnectFirm(ConnectFirmId, ConnectFirmName, editedDate) VALUES(" + ConnectFirmId + ", " + ConnectFirmName + ", " + editedDate + ", ")")
conn.commit()
print("error inserting")
```

it fails giving me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sql_test_3_d.py", line 109, in <module>
    for row in prod_orionConnectFirm_table:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Why are you connecting to db in every step of loop? Can you change the indentation?

Comment: Dont convert your values to tuple. It will throw error while concatenating with other string objects

Comment: @mad_ I am connecting to two databse servers and I am trying to have connection to both of them so I can select from one database and insert to the other one. I am not sure if I'm doing it the right way!

Answer (score 0):

prod_ConnectFirm_table will contain execution status which is an integer value which you can't over.So after executing the query as :

```
prod_ConnectFirm_table = prod_cursor.execute("select * from Common.ConnectFirm where FirmId = " + prod_source_firm + ";")
```

you need to fetch data from cursor :

```
data = prod_cursor.fetchall()
```

"data" will contain the query result in form of tuple which you parse over.

Comment: I believe it is more of a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @mad_ it would have been best if you would have edited my answer or pointed out the mistake, i would love to improve the answer and probably would have kept few things in mind while answering next time, Thanks

Comment: @dilkash your suggestion eliminated the error of TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable, but I get a different one this time Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sql_test_3_d.py", line 139, in <module>
    " + editedBy + ")")
TypeError: must be str, not int

Comment: @MinaGobrial whats the code at line 139 in sql_test_3_d.py

Comment: this one in the database is an int type! @dilkash

Comment: @MinaGobrial replace editedBy with str(editedBy) , it will get converted to string

Comment: @dilkash 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sql_test_3_d.py", line 139, in <module>
    " + str(editedBy) + ")")
TypeError: must be str, not int

Comment: @MinaGobrial, hmmm, not sure, though this error is thrown when you concatenate int with string.

Comment: and this where are the values come from:

Comment: # execute SQL query using execute() method.
ConnectFirm_table = prod_cursor.execute("select * from beta2_Common.ConnectFirm where FirmId = " + prod_source_firm + ";")
data = prod_cursor.fetchall()
for row in data:
    ConnectFirmId = row[1]
    ConnectFirmName = row[2]
    FirmId = row[3]
    isDeleted = row[4]
    tags = row[5]
    createdDate = row[6]
    createdBy = row[7]
    editedDate = row[8]
    editedBy = row[9]